# jquery include event for click and for keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

I'm working on an online calculator and I want to include both a `click` event,  where the user could click on a button, and a `keyboard` event, where he can type the numbers in a text input.
I've completed the `click` event using a `switch` block where the case is the id of each button. I want to know if there is any way I can include the `keyboard` event in the click event without writing a whole new block of code?

Comment: You can attach onkeypress or similar events to the elements(textbox) and then invoke same function as of click.

Answer (score 0):

Hier are the if conditions for keyboard what you need:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function keyDownFunc (event){ // keyboard shortcuts for using calculator
    var isShift = window.event.shiftKey ? true : false; // checks status of shift key
    if (event.keyCode == 48 || event.keyCode == 96){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } // 0
    if (event.keyCode == 49 || event.keyCode == 97){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //1
    if (event.keyCode == 50 || event.keyCode == 98){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //2
    if (event.keyCode == 51 || event.keyCode == 99){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //3
    if (event.keyCode == 52 || event.keyCode == 100){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //4
    if (event.keyCode == 53 || event.keyCode == 101){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //5
    if (event.keyCode == 54 || event.keyCode == 102){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //6
    if (event.keyCode == 55 || event.keyCode == 103){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //7
    if ((isShift == false && event.keyCode == 56) || event.keyCode == 104){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //8
    if (event.keyCode == 57 || event.keyCode == 105){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //9
    if ((isShift == true && event.keyCode == 56) || event.keyCode == 106){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //multiply
    if ((isShift == true && event.keyCode == 187) || event.keyCode == 107){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ }//add
    if (event.keyCode == 189 || event.keyCode == 109){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //subtract
    if (event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 108){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //decimal   
    if (event.keyCode == 191 || event.keyCode == 111){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //divide  
    if (event.keyCode == 220 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 12){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } // delete key 
    if ((isShift == false && event.keyCode == 187) || event.keyCode == 13){ /*Call Your Calc function hier*/ } //doMath
}, true);
```